# Fetching spesific entities in single call

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first

I am trying to fetch entities by their id properties. I know i can fetch them one by one but i think best way to fetch would be in single call. So how can i do that in below sample?

```
    internal List<Product> GetProducts(int[] productIds)
    {
        IQueryable<Product> query = ctx.Products;
        //how to fetch ?
        return query.ToList();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
internal List<Product> GetProducts(int[] productIds)
    {
        IQueryable<Product> query = ctx.Products.Where(product => productIds.Contains(product.ID));

        return query.ToList();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

are you looking for this :-

```
    var product = from p in Products
         where productid.Contains(p.Id) 
         select p;
```

Comment: How this can be happen ? You haven't write any comparing  by Id properties of products.

Answer (score 1):

```
return query.Where(x => productIds.Contains(x.ProductId)).ToList();
```